# Access Google Cloud Storage from web application, always 403

Tags: google-app-engine, web-applications, google-cloud-storage

I am work on a web application as an interface with Google Cloud Storage(GCS).

I am using a backend service to retrieve the list of files I stored on GCS and their URL with the JSON API and return that to my web application. However, I was not really able to load the files through those URL, which always came back with 403 forbidden.

I am not sure how GCS authentication work behind the scene and whether it is possible to directly grant access to web application. I am not sure how could I attach application authentication information via http request. What I know is I can do that via the backend service but for the reason of simplicity I wonder if it is possible to get around with that. One of the thing I tried is adding the web application domain(which will be sent via referrer in http request) into ACL to that bucket, which doesn't work at all.

And thanks to what @Brandon pointed out below. I am ok to grant anyone whoever have access to the application to view the content of the GCS since it is an internal app and I have already checked their authentication when I first serve the web application.

====

**Solution**

I ended up using the signedUrl that expire in 5 minutes and I highly recommend interact with gcs using **gcloud** (Their [python document](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/storage-blobs.html) is really good). Thanks again for the thorough answer!

Comment: Whose permissions do you want to use? Your application's own permissions, or the permissions of the individual users of your application (who have their own Google accounts)?

Comment: Thank @Brandon. I want to use the application permission for simplicity since it is a internal app. Also, I know it is possible that I have a backend service (if they also hosted on GAE) ask for access with the appid. But I really want to simply rely on front end for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a user on a web browser who wants to download an object that only your application's service account has read access for. You have a few options:

1. Expand access: make these object publicly readable. Probably not the best choice if this info is sensitive, but if it's not, this is the easiest solution.
2. Give your app's credentials to the user so that they can authenticate as your app. This is a REALLY bad idea, and I probably shouldn't even list it here.
3. When a user wants to download a file, have them ask your app for it, and then have your app fetch the file and stream its contents to the user. This is the easiest solution for the client-side code, but it  makes your app responsible for streaming file contents, which isn't really great.
4. When a user wants to download a file, have them ask your app for permission, and reply to them with some sort of token they can use to fetch the data directly from GCS.

#4 is what you want. Your users will ask your app for a file, your app will decide whether they are allowed to access that file via whatever you're doing (passwords? IP checks? Cookies? Whatever.) Then, your app will respond with a URL the user can use to fetch the file directly from GCS.

This URL is called a "signed URL." Your app uses its own private key to add a signature to a URL that indicates which object may be downloaded by the bearer and for long the URL is valid. The [procedure for signing URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) is somewhat tricky, but fortunately the gcloud storage libraries [have helper functions](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/storage-blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.generate_signed_url) that can generate them.

Comment: Thanks Brandon for your thorough solutions comparison. I remember one of our another application used exactly solution #4 but the API was not that friendly at the time. However, hopefully the migration to gcloud as make things now simpler.

Comment: The disadvantage of a signed url is its valid only for 7days. If you need to access the same file again after 7days, the URL needs to be generated again.